# Corrupt .drectve at end of def file GLEW

Tags: c++, static-linking, glew

I'm trying to statically compile the 64-bit GLEW library (glew32s.lib), but this results in the warning:

> Corrupt .drectve at the end of def file

The program ends up linked, but I'm worried that the warning is a result of underlying issues.

I've searched around, but all I could find was people having problems with MSVC libraries, which I do not believe that I am using and one person with a similar question who did not get an answer.

I'm still very new to command-line compilation/linking, but I believe the GLEW library I am using is the correct architecture, because using the other one provided causes ld to tell me that the library is incompatible and that ld will be ignoring it.

Comment: 64-bit GLEW is called glew32s.lib, isn't that needlessly confusing?

Comment: I agree. It's very confusing. Both the 32-bit and 64-bit GLEW seem to be called glew32s.lib. The s I believe differentiates it from the glew32.lib intended to be dynamically linked with the .dll version.